# Why printing '\0' will nullify the rest of the line in Java?

Tags: java, string, stream, io

I find out to my puzzlement that the following snippet:

```
void print() {
    System.out.print("!");
    System.out.print("!\0");
    System.out.flush(); // This line does not affect the outcome
    System.out.println("!");
    System.out.println("!");
}
```

Will only print out:

```
!!
!
```

I searched the Open JDK's source code for the implementation, but no avail.

The only clue have the clue that it seems `BufferedOutputStream`, and it seem to also have the similar "terminate on \u0000" behavior.

Also I cannot find any documentation about this pretty unexpected (for me) behavior.

EDIT: My environment:

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

IDE: Eclipse Indigo 3.7.0
```

EDIT AGAIN: Under command line, this code works as expected (four "!"s). So it seems to be a bug for Eclipse 3.7.0 Indigo under Ubuntu?

(Should be) FINAL EDIT: It seems that as irreputable and amir75 said, this is not a quirk of Java: I redirected the output of Eclipse to a file, and if I open it up in Eclipse, the content only have three "!"s; but when using `cat` from the command line, there are four. In addition, vi and emacs both show `!!^@!` for the first line, which is as expected. Thank you all!

Could anybody shed some light on this? Is this required anywhere in Java Spec? Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The following prints 4 `!`s, as expected: http://ideone.com/HrKZE

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: @Matt Ball: I've updated the post with my environment information. Is this an implementation specific thing, or is this a bug in OpenJDK / Eclipse? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running in the IDE, or from the command line?

Comment: It also works for me in Eclipse Indigo on OS X 10.6.

Comment: @Dave Newton: In the IDE. I'll try command line, and edit this in a moment. EDIT: It worked! Updated post. Thanks! Now I have regained the bit of confidence in Java I lost due to this quirk:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is terminal-dependent: I just tried in Eclipse, and it reproduced your error. On commandline, it didn't.

I think this can be expected, because most languages since C use `\0` ( a null byte) internally to signify the end of a String.

Thanks to the late, great Dennis Ritchie, that's how stuff works.

Answer (score 2):

Java probably has no control over the behavior - it is the console that determines how to interpret the bytes. The console doesn't always print as is; some bytes may even cause color change or make beeps.